# Issues while making some kind of menu

Tags: c++, menu, mouse, allegro, allegro5

I made this thing as a part of my program. Language is C++, with Allegro libraries. I want to make it do the next: when clicking, a border appears around one of the two rectangulars.

It happens, but only once, at the beginning. After that, the border disappears all the time when I move the mouse away. Also, anywhere I click, the border appears on the proper place.

mouseX and mouseY works perfectly, even the numbers are the same. But the action happens only once on the way I want. How to expand it to every cases when I'm clicking?

```
    if(asd.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_AXES)
    {
        mouseX = asd.mouse.x;
        mouseY = asd.mouse.y;
    }

    if(asd.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_BUTTON_DOWN)
    {
        if(asd.mouse.button & 1)
        {
            if (mouseX > 592 && mouseX < 608 && mouseY > 540 && mouseY < 556)
            {
                Chosen_Cell = 1;
                borderX = 592;
                borderY = 540;
            }

            if (mouseX > 592 && mouseX < 608 && mouseY > 556 && mouseY < 562)
            {
                Chosen_Cell = 2;
                borderX = 592;
                borderY = 556;
            }

            al_draw_rectangle(borderX, borderY, borderX + 16, borderY + 16, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 0),2);

            if (16 < mouseX && mouseX < 528 && 16 < mouseY &&mouseY < 736)
            {
                switch (Chosen_Cell)
                {
                                        //blahblah, not important
                }   
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border is disappearing because you are calling your drawing code within the button down event. This means as soon as the button is released, the rectangle will no longer show up. It's usually better practice to have events update values, and then have everything on the screen drawn when the event queue is empty and a redraw is called by a timer.

```
//setup a timer and a redraw var
ALLEGRO_TIMER *timer;
bool redraw = false;

timer = al_create_timer(1.0/FPS);

al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_timer_event_source(timer));
al_start_timer(timer);

while(running)
{
    if(asd.type == ALEGRO_EVENT_TIMER)
        redraw = true;
    if(asd.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_BUTTON_DOWN)
    {
        if(asd.mouse.button & 1)
        {
           if (mouseX > 592 && mouseX < 608 && mouseY > 540 && mouseY < 556)
           {
               Chosen_Cell = 1;
               borderX = 592;
               borderY = 540;
           }

           if (mouseX > 592 && mouseX < 608 && mouseY > 556 && mouseY < 562)
           {
               Chosen_Cell = 2;
               borderX = 592;
               borderY = 556;
           }
       } 
    if(redraw && al_is_event_queue_empty(asd))
    {
        al_draw_rectangle(borderX, borderY, borderX + 16, borderY + 16, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 0),2);
        redraw = false;
        al_flip_display();
        al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: `asd` is an event, so the condition wants to be `al_is_event_queue_empty(_name of the event queue_)` instead I think.

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't seem to work: the only thing I can see is a flash. Also, this emthod makes the run of the other part of the program very slow.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt: If it didn't work... *why did you accept it*?

Comment: Because the question is not important anymore but I couldn't delete since it already has an answer.